# Get creation date of Xcode project

Tags: xcode, plist, xcode-project

The question is pretty simple, is there a .plist attribute or something like this where the creation date of a Xcode project .xcodeproj is saved?

I can not use the file system creation date, because I copied and pasted the project very often and the metadata are corrupted.

I tried the tool [EasyFind](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) to search for the creation year in all files of my project, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask apple support and they say that there is no creation date saved!

Answer (score 0):

Just open up a file that you are sure has been there since the start of the project, e.g. the file containing the App Life Cycle, and do:

1. Right click -> `Show in Finder`
2. (In Finder) Right click -> `Get Info`
3. Search for the `Created` tag

Then you got it.